# Lost check made out to a school organization

Tags: bank-account, check, fraud

Today I lost a sizeable check made out to a school club. What should I do? Can anyone who finds this check use my acct number to withdraw funds?

Currently, the check has not gone through or been cashed yet.

Comment: Can it be misused? technically yes but the reality of it is debatable. What you should do is notify the bank that the check is lost and place a hold on it. Keep in mind, they do not guarantee that it will stop it from being processed but it is your best shot at this point - short of closing the account and/or rolling it into another account with a different number - which some banks offer but might be more trouble than it is worth.

Comment: You should be able to cancel the specific cheque number (assuming you haven't written any other cheques since, it should be N-1 where N is the number on the current top cheque in your chequebook.)

Answer (score 1):

Call the bank and ask them to cancel the check. You should know its sequence number, and that's the information which the bank needs to "stop payment".

They will probably charge you a modest fee for this service.

Ask them specifically if they need you to additionally make this request in writing - some banks apparently do, according to https://www.thebalance.com/stop-payment-315346.

And ask if the "stop-payment" request will need to be renewed after some period. Some banks don't maintain these requests beyond six months or so.